# ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error in my C# code

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

I am learning C# these days and still a beginner.

While practicing creating methods, I made this method that yields the sum of the members of a numeric array (my codes are massive and I am not good at math). 
VS returns an ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error, but I don't know how to fix this. 
Please save me!

```
  public static int SumAll(int[] a)
    {
        List<int> sum = new List<int>();
        int sumAll;



        if (a.Length == 0)
        {
            sumAll = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sum[0] = a[0];


            for (int i = 1; i < (a.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + a[i];
            }

            sumAll = sum[a.Length - 1];
        }
        return sumAll;  
    }
```

Comment: Your list `sum` is empty and you try to access a missing first element with `sum[0]`. Also you don't need the sum list for just adding all elements, you could do that with `sumAll`. However if you still want to use `sumAll`, initialize the list with `List<int> sum = new List<int>();` and replace the line `sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + a[i];` with `sum[i] = sum[i] + sum[i - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

Use the **+=** [addition assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator):

```
public static int SumAll(int[] a) 
{
  int sumAll = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < (a.Length - 1); i++) 
  { 
    sumAll += a[i]; 
  }
  return sumAll;
}
```

The ArgumentOutOfRangeException is typically to do with an item out of the range of an array, collection or list.. Because you use a `List<int> sum` you are not adding items to it. `sum.Add(a[i]);` and that's why you get the exception; the sum variable doesn't have any items.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that exception is because you are trying to assign a value to an index in the List that doesn't exist yet when you do this:

```
sum[0] = a[0];
```

Instead, you should just use the `.Add` method to add items to the List. Once they're added, you can access them by index. The reason for this is that the list is not pre-populated to any set size (whereas an array is), so to begin with there is nothing at `[0]`.

```
sum.Add(a[0]);
```

You will also get this exception here:

```
sumAll = sum[a.Length - 1];
```

This is because the `sum` List will only contain `a.Length - 2` items (your loop stops when `i == a.Length - 1`). This is a bug in your code! You should be using `i < a.Length` as the condition:

```
for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
```

This way you are looping through **ALL** the items in your `a` array.

Your method would then look something like this (notice I also added a check for `a == null`):

```
public static int SumAll(int[] a)
{
    if (a == null) return 0;

    List<int> sum = new List<int>();
    int sumAll;

    if (a.Length == 0)
    {
        sumAll = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        sum.Add(a[0]);


        for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            sum.Add(sum[i - 1] + a[i]);
        }

        sumAll = sum[a.Length - 1];
    }

    return sumAll;
}
```

Now, this code could be simplified if you wanted, by removing the list, starting with `sumAll = 0`, and then just adding each item from `a` to it in your loop:

```
public static int SumAll(int[] a)
{
    if (a == null) return 0;

    int sumAll = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        sumAll += a[i];
    }

    return sumAll;
}
```

Or you can *really* shorten it by using the `System.Linq` extension method, `Sum`:

```
public static int SumAll(int[] a)
{
    return a == null ? 0 : a.Sum();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!! It really  helped a lot!!